# Pandas DatetimeIndex string format conversion from American to European

Tags: python, pandas

Ok I have read some data from a CSV file using:

```
df=pd.read_csv(path,index_col='Date',parse_dates=True,dayfirst=True)
```

The data are in European date convention format `dd/mm/yyyy`, that is why i am using `dayfirst=True.`

However, what i want to do is change the string format appearance of my dataframe index df from the American`(yyyy/mm/dd)` to the European format`(dd/mm/yyyy)` just to visually been consistent with how i am looking the dates.

I could't find any relevant argument in the `pd.read_csv` method.

In the output I want a dataframe in which simply the index will be a datetime index visually consistent with the European date format.

Could anyone propose a solution? It should be straightforward, since I guess there should be a pandas method to handle that, but i am currently stuck.

Comment: I think this can works - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7577, but for me not. Maybe still bug.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like the following once it's loaded from the CSV. I don't believe it's possible to perform the conversion as part of the reading process.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='11/24/2016', periods=4)})
df['date_eu'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem is that i need my index to be `datetimeIndex`.  When I try to convert the `date_eu` to `datetimeIndex` it flips again the date to the American format(so visually the consistency i lost again)

Comment: The format actually follows the internationally accepted ISO-8601 format. I don't know of a way to change the presentation of a datetime object.